When using Gradle 8, you must set the JAVA17_HOME environment variable to the location of a Java 17 JDK
I’ve been unable to build codenameone Android Gradle Projects since upgrading on NetBeans 12.6 to codenameone-maven-plugin:7.0.150.  Receiving the following error message:
Generating android gradle Project to /Users/mike/IT/NetBeansProjects/myapp/android/target/myapp-android-1.0-SNAPSHOT-android-source...
Starting android project builder...
Failed to build Android project with error: When using gradle 8, you must set the JAVA17_HOME environment variable to the location of a Java 17 JDK


com.codename1.builders.BuildException: When using gradle 8, you must set the JAVA17_HOME environment variable to the location of a Java 17 JDK
    at com.codename1.builders.AndroidGradleBuilder.getGradleJavaHome (AndroidGradleBuilder.java:440)
    at com.codename1.builders.AndroidGradleBuilder.build (AndroidGradleBuilder.java:489)
    at com.codename1.maven.CN1BuildMojo.doAndroidLocalBuild (CN1BuildMojo.java:847)
    at com.codename1.maven.CN1BuildMojo.createAntProject (CN1BuildMojo.java:562)
    at com.codename1.maven.CN1BuildMojo.executeImpl (CN1BuildMojo.java:116)
    at com.codename1.maven.AbstractCN1Mojo.execute (AbstractCN1Mojo.java:195)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:61)

As Shai suggested, I created MyTestApp from Codename One Initializr at start.codenameone.com.
It runs fine from the command line on JDK 17 but fails on the android build ./build.sh android_source
Does that mean there is a compatibility issue with JDK 17 and I should be using a different Java JDK?  Here’s a few key lines of output:
[INFO] <<< codenameone-maven-plugin:7.0.86:build (build-android) < package @ mytestapp-android <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- codenameone-maven-plugin:7.0.86:build (build-android) @ mytestapp-android ---
[INFO] Running ANT build target android-source
[INFO] Generating android gradle Project to /Users/mike/IT/NetBeansProjects/mytestapp/android/target/mytestapp-android-1.0-SNAPSHOT-android-source...
[INFO] Starting android project builder...
[INFO] Executing with timeout -1
[INFO] Exception in thread "main" 
[INFO] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)

[INFO] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 5 more

[INFO] Process return code is 1
[INFO] Executing with timeout -1
[INFO] 

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.8.3

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-02-22 16:13:28 UTC

[INFO] Revision:     9e26b4a9ebb910eaa1b8da8ff8575e514bc61c78

Kotlin:       1.4.20
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
[INFO] 
JVM:          17.0.11 (Oracle Corporation 17.0.11+7-LTS-207)
OS:           Mac OS X 14.3.1 aarch64


[INFO] Process return code is 0
[INFO] TargetSDKVersion= android:targetSdkVersion="31" 
[INFO] Creating AndroidStudioProject from template
[INFO] Executing: 
[INFO] /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dretrolambda.inputDir=/Users/mike/IT/NetBeansProjects/mytestapp/android/target/codenameone/antProject/dist/android-build/Classes -Dretrolambda.classpath=/Users/mike/IT/NetBeansProjects/mytestapp/android/target/codenameone/antProject/dist/android-build/Classes:/Users/mike/.m2/repository/com/codenameone/codenameone-core/7.0.150/codenameone-core-7.0.150.jar -Dretrolambda.outputDir=/Users/mike/IT/NetBeansProjects/mytestapp/android/target/codenameone/antProject/dist/android-build/Classes_retrolamda -Dretrolambda.bytecodeVersion=49 -Dretrolambda.defaultMethods=true -jar /Users/mike/.m2/repository/net/orfjackal/retrolambda/retrolambda/2.5.7/retrolambda-2.5.7.jar 
[INFO] Executing with timeout -1
[INFO] Retrolambda 2.5.7

[INFO] 00:00  INFO: Bytecode version: 49 (Java 5)

[INFO] 00:00  INFO: Default methods:  true
00:00  INFO: Input directory:  /Users/mike/IT/NetBeansProjects/mytestapp/android/target/codenameone/antProject/dist/android-build/Classes
00:00  INFO: Output directory: /Users/mike/IT/NetBeansProjects/mytestapp/android/target/codenameone/antProject/dist/android-build/Classes_retrolamda

[INFO] 00:00  INFO: Classpath:        [/Users/mike/IT/NetBeansProjects/mytestapp/android/target/codenameone/antProject/dist/android-build/Classes, /Users/mike/.m2/repository/com/codenameone/codenameone-core/7.0.150/codenameone-core-7.0.150.jar]
00:00  INFO: Included files:   all
00:00  INFO: JVM version:      17.0.11
00:00  INFO: Agent enabled:    false
00:00  INFO: javac hacks:      false

[INFO] 00:00 ERROR: Failed to run Retrolambda
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize dumper; unexpected JDK implementation. Please run Retrolambda using the Java agent (enable forking in the Maven plugin).
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.lambdas.LambdaClassDumper.install(LambdaClassDumper.java:38)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.Retrolambda.run(Retrolambda.java:67)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.Main.main(Main.java:28)
    Suppressed: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class net.orfjackal.retrolambda.lambdas.LambdaClassDumper cannot access a member of class java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory (in module java.base) with modifiers "private static final"
        at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.lambdas.LambdaClassDumper.uninstall(LambdaClassDumper.java:48)
        at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.lambdas.LambdaClassDumper.close(LambdaClassDumper.java:55)
        at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.Retrolambda.run(Retrolambda.java:102)
        ... 1 more


So - did you?

Yes.  Same error message.

Your OS is ...?

MacOS 14.3.1 (23D60)

(New Terminal instance) What does echo $JAVA17_HOME have to say?

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk   I have the following line in the .zshrc file:  export JAVA17_HOME='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home'. not sure why the Contents/Home part doesn't show up on the echo.

And find $JAVA17_HOME -name javac?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Sometimes the environment isn't picked up by the IDE. Go into the project settings and add the environment explicitly there. I've had issues with the shell not picking up the environment properly.

@ShaiAlmog - In codenameone_settings.properties I added the build hint: codename1.arg.java.version=8 but I still get
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk even though echo $JAVA_HOME from terminal on Mac gives
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_321.jdk/Contents/Home - Is there a CN1 buildhint to specify this path to the Java 8 jdk?

The java.version=8 is unrelated and should always be set that way. The terminal often gives different results from the IDE since those are separate processes. You can try CLI builds and see that the build will pass in the CLI. That means the environment value isn't passing correctly in the IDE.

@Shai - I’ve run build from the command line as you suggested.  See updated question above.  Does that mean there is a codenameone compatibility issue with JDK 17 and I should be using a different Java JDK?

Codename One doesn't work with JDK 17. You need to set the PATH and JAVA_HOME to JDK 11 or JDK 8. That's crucial for Codename One. No other JDK is supported for Codename One. If you only use the cloud build this works out of the box. For local building you need to build on Android which requires JDK 17. That's why we introduced JAVA17_HOME which is a separate JDK install that must be outside of your path. Unfortunately, Mac is notoriously bad at multi-JDK installs. It might be picking up your last install as the default and using JDK 17. Try installing JDK 11 so Codename One uses that.

Thx @ShaiAlmog.  Building the Android Gradle Project from Netbeans I couldn’t get it to  pick up the JAVA17_HOME path but it did work from the CLI after I changed the name of the JDK 17 folder.  See accepted answer.

Changing the Java 17 folder name from jdk-17.jdk to jdk-17.0.11.jdk fixed the problem.
Originally
JDK 17 Foldername:
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk

In .zshrc file:
export JAVA17_HOME='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home'

echo $JAVA17_HOME:
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk

/Contents/Home was missing from echo'd path
Revised
JDK 17 Foldername:
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.11.jdk

In .zshrc file:
export JAVA17_HOME='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.11.jdk/Contents/Home'

echo $JAVA17_HOME:
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.11.jdk/Contents/Home

/Contents/Home doesn't get clipped!

I had a similar problem on Linux when generating a Android gradle project using latest Codename One versions like 7.0.142 which requires gradle 8 by default.
To resolve this I
• Installed Java-17
• Use geddit to edit etc/environment file
• Add Java-17 installation PATH and JAVA17_HOME variable to etc/environment
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-open-jdk-amd64/bin"
JAVA17_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-open-jdk-amd64/"
Note the : which appends multiple paths
• Save and restart PC to apply changes to the environment.
Without restarting PC, project generation still failed since new changes to environment hadn't applied.
You can try these steps in Mac to set up environment

Thx.  Sorry I'm not skilled enough to convert these instructions from PC to Mac.  Interesting that Codenameone requires JDK 17 since the documentation online still says JDK 8 (https://www.codenameone.com/developer-guide.html#_eclipse).

This isn't for Codename One. This is separate from our JDK required only for native local source generation and is required by Android, not by us. Generally Eric is saying that the problem is the path isn't reaching the build code. In Windows you would edit the path/environment in the Global control panel settings and reboot.

I haven't used Mac but you can try the following options which discuss about setting environment variables in .profileor .bash_profile or ~/.zshrc ~/.zprofile.        https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106778/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-on-os-x
